How to call snowflake procedure with arguments from adf
i have a master table as EMP_NAME with few values in it and column name as EMPNAME. I want to pass these values as argument to a snowflake procedure which will create tables with employee name in snowflake.
Lookup activity
Passed values from Lookup to foreach
Foreach
Inside for each
Please help to guide on how to use script activity with new snowflake conenctor
I have tried to use lookup activity after that for each.But not able to figure out inside how should i use script activity

You can use the concat() expression to concatenate the stored procedure calling script and the lookup item in each iteration like below. Here, item().emp_name is the current lookup item in the For-each activity. Use the below expression in the script activity inside for-each activity.
@concat('call tablecheck(''',item().emp_name,''')')


If the passing value is not a string or date value, you can remove the '' in the script.
You can also use string concatenation @{} to specify the dynamic expression in the query like below.
call tablecheck('@{item().emp_name}')

You can cross check the script in the input of the script activity.

